# Filling select box from parent select box in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, multi-select

I want to implement the following image in my application:

[image]
Here i want to fill the second box with selected items from first box when clicking on `ADD` button.

How can i implement this with cakephp.

Iam new in cakephp

Image in google:

http://lh4.ggpht.com/70kyxWGqbi72F5L-DjvJ09UUkDVpXjsS5_6_ndgjRfPE7hmNfnlXRCxNzddgBcfh8YqI6w=s162

If there is any solution for this?

Comment: Structure is not visible

Comment: @Shashwat can you see the above image.....?

Comment: No. Lets wait what others say.

Comment: @Shashwat ok the image is viewable to me...

Comment: @Shashwat it is bmp image so if there is any problem with that.....?

Comment: @Shashwat can you check it now refresh your browser i also updated the image.....

Comment: Its still not there. I checked it in Firefox10 and IE 8. Not sure whats is the problem.

Comment: @Shashwat ok i uploaded in google: `http://lh4.ggpht.com/70kyxWGqbi72F5L-DjvJ09UUkDVpXjsS5_6_ndgjRfPE7hmNfnlXRCxNzddgBcfh8YqI6w=s162` check this ....

Comment: @Shashwat can you see it now....?

Comment: Yes. I can see the image but sorry I don't know the answer. Just commented to tell you that the image is not visible to viewers. :)

Comment: @Shashwat ok ok ok..............

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can do it with PHP, but I think jQuery would be a easier and better option

```
$("#move").click(function(){
    $("#one :selected").each(function(index, item){
        $("#two").append(item);
    });
});​
```

Check the working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4fCFb/

Comment: that means the selected items is placed into second select boxbut not removed from select box

Comment: Then use a `clone()` when doing the append to the second list

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin that creates this effect from a single multiselect box. Give this one a look:

http://www.quasipartikel.at/multiselect/